# Cannot Get using forms in Node.js Express

Tags: forms, node.js, express, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use a form to submit to the website so that I can render the website.

this is my form

```
div.ten.columns#LogModal
        h3 Log In
        p
            a.button(href='#', data-reveal-id='exampleModal') Example modal
    div#exampleModal.reveal-modal
        h2 Log In
        p
            form(method='get', action='/Log')
                input(type='text', placeholder='Username', name='Username', id='Username')
                input(type='password', placeholder='Password', name='Password', id='Username')
                input(type='submit', value='Log in', id='LogButton')

    script(src='javascripts/foundation.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/app.js')
    script
      $(window).load(function(){
      $("#featured").orbit();
      });
```

And its just going through the server.js like so

```
app.get('/Log', User.Home);
```

and eventually renders a webpage like so:

```
exports.Home = function (req, res) {
res.render('MyHome'); };
```

and all that results in this error:

```
Cannot GET /Log?Username=&Password=&LogButton=Log+in
```

I want it to work without any log in information at this point because its just for demonstration right now.   Can anybody help me?

Comment: You really should be using POST for a login form, take at look @ https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable and if if it helps.

Comment: Would that fix it?  I know I should be using post but I'll be changing that when I actually add the functionality.  Right now I just want it to go from page to page.  Thats why I'm using get

Comment: Not sure, looking at the code you've posted, everything should be working, without seeing more I can only make stabs at possible failure points, and point out useful modules you will need shortly.  The only explanation I can see right now is that `app.get('/Log' . . .)` isn't being attached.

Comment: what do you mean by attached?

Comment: That the line is in your code but never being run, or the like.

Comment: Oh yea, because for some reason its looking for /Log?Username=&Password=&LogButton=Log+in

Comment: What's the markup language you have used for your website?

Answer (score 1):

app.get('/Log', User.Home);

In this function, if User.Home is not defined then you will get this error.
Does Home function exist in User model?

Just create one function(lets say 'demoHome') with any name in server.js and call it here like..

app.get('/Log', demoHome);

where demoHome function will be defined as..

var demoHome = function(req, res){ somecode here with proper response or render any page here using res.rendere('path/of/template')};

Comment: Hm, when I moved the function that was supposed to be called at User.Home, it worked.  I wonder why my User.js file isn't mapped properly

Comment: Just figured it out, I had module.exports = User at the top of my User.js file, I guess that inerfered

Comment: Did you add User.js in your server.js? In User.js your function will be like User.Home = function(something){something}; I think exports.Home = function(something){something} is not correct.